Getting Error While doing login with facebook and LinkedIn in reactjs
I'm implementing login with facebook and LinkedIn using React.js. getting below error's unable to resolve this. used below packages react-facebook-login and react-linkedin-login-oauth2
import React from 'react';
import { useLinkedIn } from "react-linkedin-login-oauth2";
import linkedin from "react-linkedin-login-oauth2/assets/linkedin.png";
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login/dist/facebook-login-render-props';

const FaceBookLoginProvider = () => {
    const responseFacebook = (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    };

    return (
        <FacebookLogin
            appId="498310359268039"
            autoLoad={true}
            fields="name,email,picture"
            callback={responseFacebook}
        />
    );
}
function LinkedInLoginProvider() {
    const { linkedInLogin } = useLinkedIn({
        clientId: '86wj5ppsvt1dzo',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/linkedin',
        onSuccess: (code) => {
            console.log(code);
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        },
    });
    return (
        <>
            <img
                src={linkedin}
                alt="Log in with Linked In"
                style={{ maxWidth: '180px' }}
                onClick={linkedInLogin}
            />
        </>
    );
}

export { FaceBookLoginProvider, LinkedInLoginProvider }

Imported in the App.js file:
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <FaceBookLoginProvider />
    <LinkedInLoginProvider />
    </>
  );
}
export default App;

I'm using below react version, and package related details:
react version is ^18.2.0.
react-facebook-login: "^4.1.1",
react-linkedin-login-oauth2: "^2.0.1".
While clicking on the facebook button, getting below errors:
in .env file given HTTPS=true.
Below facebook error is coming on page load also, even without clicking on facebook button.

in console we are getting bellow error:

For, linkedIn getting below error in the pop-up:

Below are the steps followed to create app and appid:

created facebook account - https://developers.facebook.com/
selected developer option.
while creating app selected, other option and selecting consumer.
did setup, facebook login and given site URL - http://localhost/
in app setting in basic gave app domain as - localhost

Below are the steps followed to create app and clientid in linkedIn:

created developer linkedin account and got it verified.
in products enabled - Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect
in auth Authorized redirect URLs for your app given - http://localhost:3000


net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT usually indicates that an ad blocker or privacy enhancing extension or browser setting prevented loading the resource.

Hi @CBroe, thank you for your response. getting some typeError also. do you think because of net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT we are getting that typeError???

It is probably likely that the two are connected, yes.

tried in brave, chrome, edge all three browsers giving the same response. any idea where we can check this blocker or privacy settings

tried many ways. but, didn't work

could someone help me on signin with linkedin getting above mentioned error
